# Using ContentChildren to get all the router links on a page

Tags: angular, angular-router

If I add a content children to my component

```
@ContentChildren(RouterLink, { descendants: true })
links: QueryList<RouterLink>;
```

and have a template

```
<a [routerLink]="''">Link 1</a><br>
<a [routerLink]="''">Link 2</a><br>
<a [routerLink]="''">Link 3</a><br>
Number of links: {{links.length}}
```

Links length is always 0.

I have tried with a directive as well

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appRouterLinkWatch]'
})
export class RouterLinkWatchDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(RouterLink, { descendants: true })
  links: QueryList<RouterLink>;

  constructor(@Optional() private link: RouterLink) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.links.length, this.link);
  }
}
```

Both the links content children and the link dependency are not populated. What am I doing wrong to get a list of router links in my component?

I have been looking at the sorce code for the routerLinkActive directive
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts
I cannot see what I am doing differently.

I have a stack blitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bvpyhd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I managed to get a length on the ContentChildren when changing the type to `RouterLinkWithHref`, however I am not certain when one type should be used over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the `RouterLink` directive utilizes two separate types internally.

`RouterLink` and `RouterLinkWithHref`

### Counting `routerLink` directly in component

If we want to count the `routerLinks` directly in the component, and expect no projected links, then we must use `@ViewChildren()` rather than `@ContentChildren()`.

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(RouterLink) routeWithoutHref!: QueryList<RouterLink>;
  @ViewChildren(RouterLinkWithHref) routeWithHref!: QueryList<RouterLinkWithHref>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.routeWithHref.length); // expect 2
    console.log(this.routeWithoutHref.length); // expect 1
  }
}
```

```html
<a routerLink>link</a>
<a routerLink="a">link</a>
<div routerLink="b">link</div>
```

The above component produces a length of 2 for `RouterLinkWithHref` and a length of 1 for `RouterLink` from which I summize it depends on whether the `RouterLink` is attached to an anchor or not.

Whether the directive has any input does not appear to bear any influence.

### Counting RouterLink from a directive

Much the same as before, except we now utilize `ContentChildren` instead of `ViewChildren`

```
@Directive({selector: '[countRoutes]'})
export class RouteCountDirective implements AfterContentInit{
  @ContentChildren(RouterLink, {descendants: true}) routerLinks!: QueryList<RouterLink>
  @ContentChildren(RouterLinkWithHref, {descendants: true}) routerLinksWithHref!: QueryList<RouterLinkWithHref>

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.routerLinks.length) // 1
    console.log(this.routerLinksWithHref.length) // 2
  }
}
```

```html
<div countRoutes>
  <a routerLink>link</a>
  <a routerLink="a">link</a>
  <div routerLink="b">link</div>
</div>
```

**Notice**

When using the `{descendants: true}` option for the `ContentChildren` only `routerLinks` nested inside the element on which the `countRoutes` directive is attached will be selected.

```html
<div countRoutes>
  <a routerLink>Counted</a>
  <a routerLink="a">Counted</a>
  <div routerLink="b">Counted</div>
</div>
<a routerLink="c">Not Counted</a>
```